# How to generate empty arrays named from another list

Tags: python, arrays

What I want to do is take a list and generate an arrays that include the item in the other array. This is what I tried:

```
def GenerateArray(pers):
    for item in pers:
        (newtest30 + str(item)) = []
        (newtest60 + str(item)) = []
        (newtest120 + str(item)) = []
        (newtest5min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest10min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest15min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest20min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest25min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest30min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest35min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest40min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest45min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest50min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest55min + str(item)) = []
        (newtest60min + str(item)) = []
```

for example for a list like this `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` I want arrays generated named

```
newtest301
newtest302
newtest303
etc
```

How do I do this since the above code doesn't work thanks.

Comment: Creating dynamic variable names is bad practice since it is more difficult to maintain/debug. Use a list of lists or a dictionary of lists instead.

Comment: Also, don't name a variable `list` (or any other built-in python type or keyword)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically creating variable names is really hard to maintain.  It is possible (currently) in Cpython (though other implementations may work differently) and it's not guaranteed to always work in Cpython.  In other words...doing this is a **BAD IDEA**.  But, if you must:

```
globals()['a']='foo'
print(a)   #prints foo
```

**A much better way to do this is to just use a dictionary.**

```
def GenerateArray(pers):
    d={}
    for item in pers:
        d['newtest30' + str(item)] = []

    return d
```

Then you can get at your list via:

```
d=GenerateArray([1,2,3])
test301=d['newtest301']
```

This has the advantage that it allows you to iterate over your tests much easier than it would have been if you dynamically named them.  (For example, how would you know how many newtest's you had created?)

Comment: I didn't realize what I was trying to do is such a bad idea but this worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't want dynamically named variables: that's a definite **Bad Idea (tm)**

What you could do is use a `dict` something like:

```
from itertools import product

def generate_arrays(pers):
    blah = [
        'newtest30',
        'newtest60'
        # etc...
    ]
    my_dict = dict( ('{}{}'.format(a, b), list()) for a, b in product(blah, pers) )
    return my_dict
```

But if you find yourself doing this, it's probably a design flaw.